# Why am I getting this error in Speech to text code?

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I use watson speech to text node.js sdk to develop a "speech to text" module using react. I'm stuck at this final step where I'm getting an error instead of output.

[image]

Apparently it says the "GET https://localhost:3002/api/speech-to-text/token net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: gather more information and find a particular detail which you are unable to solve. A websocket connection may fail due to many reasons as newbie pointed. Please see if this is server issue / client issue / handshake issue or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of reason could cause this, some are platform or browser specific, but to start with .
1) Is the website up and listening on that port ?
2) Is you firewall configured to allow traffic ?

Comment: @Thivya Give an explanation on how you solved this when you accepted the resolution. It will be useful for future readers if the same problem occurs

Comment: @RC0993 yes sure. In my case, it was the latter one. My firewall has been blocking the traffic. This resolved my issue.